# How to merge multiple rasters to multiple rasters with ArcMap model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have two folders with parts of rasters that I want to merge each, using the modeler:

Folder 1

- area1_part_1
- area2_part_1
- area3_part_1
- ...

Folder 2

- area1_part_2
- area2_part_2
- area3_part_2
- ...

(output) Folder 3

- area1_part1+part2
- area2_part1+part2
- area3_part1+part2
- ...

This is my model right now:
[image]

Since you can't use two iterators, I made a sub-model. However when I run everything, Input 1 iterates correctly but it always merges with the last file from Input 2. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest solution is to ensure Folders 1 and Folders 2 sit in the same sub-folder then all you need to do is tick on *Recursive* in the Iterator, make sure your output folder is not in the same sub-folder

So for example:

```
c:\temp
     \Folder1
     \Folder2
```

**BUT**

If you look at the syntax section of the help file for the tool Mosaic To New Raster it takes a *list* of rasters. So what you need to do is feed the output of an iterator into the model only Collect Values tool, this creates your list of rasters. All this must be in a sub-model exposing the output of the collects tool as a parameter. Drop that sub-model into the master model with nothing more than the Mosaic To New Raster tool and connect it. Look at [my answer to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94990/how-to-merge-output-shapefiles-in-model-builder/95083#95083) if you are unsure about sub-model and collect tools and how to connect