# Using iterator to merge Excel files into Shapefile with ModelBuilder for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iteration

[image: ModelIterateXLSFiles]

Using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS 10.2 I want to iterate through a folder containing .xls-files, convert them to tables, and merge them into one Shapefile.

I tried the script Excel To Table, with and without the Collect Values tool, the model runs, but it gives no output at all.

What is wrong with my model?

Comment: The Excep docs, d they contain xy coordinates? A merge only works with features and shapefiles. If you have coordinates perhaps the the create xy event layer and then merge.

Comment: Yes, the records do contain xy coordinates. I will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Your model is inefficient as you are merging  on each iteration, your model will run considerably faster if you build your model correctly. See my answer this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94990/how-to-merge-output-shapefiles-in-model-builder/95083#95083) and try to understand the use of sub-models.

Comment: I will check that out and make changes accordingly. I appreciate the help.